# Is it possible to create in matplotlib sidebars with the shape of the data points?

Tags: matplotlib

Similar to the following image (which it seems was generated by hand):
[image]

Is it possible to generate the areas circled in purple using matplotlib?

I know it is possible to have sidebars with the relevant color/density however I am interested in the shape itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply plot the items again with a fixed x and y respectively. Since by default items outside the axes are clipped, you have to set `clip_on` to False when plotting.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#stars
x1 = np.random.rand(4)
y1 = np.random.rand(4)

# circles
x2 = np.random.rand(4)
y2 = np.random.rand(4)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'aspect': 1, 'xlim': [0,1], 'ylim': [0,1]})

star_style = {'linestyle': 'none', 'marker': (5,1), 'ms': 16, 'mec': 'r', 'mfc': 'none', 'mew': 2}
circ_style = {'linestyle': 'none', 'marker': 'o', 'ms': 14, 'mec': 'b', 'mfc': 'none', 'mew': 2}

ax.plot(x1, y1, **star_style)
ax.plot(np.full_like(x1, -0.1), y1, clip_on=False, **star_style)
ax.plot(x1, np.full_like(y1, -0.1), clip_on=False, **star_style)

ax.plot(x2, y2, **circ_style)
ax.plot(np.full_like(x2, -0.1), y2, clip_on=False, **circ_style)
ax.plot(x2, np.full_like(y2, -0.1), clip_on=False, **circ_style)
```

[image]